# Custom Audience Targeting

Tags: spfx, audience-targeting, spfx-extensions

I'm doing some research on how to create a custom solution for audience Targeting since there is no build-in support yet.

Do anyone have some ideas on how to achieve that?

I have already some ideas, my first was to create a SharePoint Extension.

For the first step, I need a way to get a reference to all current running Web parts.

Is there a way to get them over the current context?

Thank you in advance!